# General coercion to BigDecimal

Tags: ruby

I'm validating some geospatial data and I need to coerce other datatypes into a BigDecimal.

The closest I can get is via the following code snippet:

```
def is_decimalizable?(coordinate)
  !coordinate.to_d.zero?
end
```

Of course, `to_d` returns zero for invalid coercions, which makes valid zero-like number-like constructs fail the test. I can't really see a better way in the `BigDecimal` docs, though. (There's a `BigDecimal#coerce` method that doesn't really document helpful usecases.)

```
# Good:
is_decimalizable?(-100)        #=> true
is_decimalizable?('-100')      #=> true
is_decimalizable?(-100.0)      #=> true
is_decimalizable?('-100.0')    #=> true
is_decimalizable?('-100.0lng') #=> true
bigd = BigDecimal.new('0.1')
is_decimalizable?(bigd)        #=> true

is_decimalizable?('asdf')      #=> false

# Bad:
is_decimalizable?(0)          #=> false
is_decimalizable?('0')        #=> false
is_decimalizable?(0.0)        #=> false
is_decimalizable?('0.0')      #=> false
is_decimalizable?('0.0lng')   #=> false
bigd = BigDecimal.new('0.0')
is_decimalizable?(bigd)       #=> false
```

Anyone got a more robust solution for this? I'm using ruby2.0.0-p0 for what it's worth.

Comment: Wow, what a massive inconsistent PITA! `Float('pancakes')` raises an exception but `BigDecimal('pancakes')` returns zero.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I figured an ugly mishmash of `is_a?`, `respond_to?`, and regexes would be about as good as you could get.

Comment: I ended up going with a regex entirely. I'd love a method-based way of doing it, but found no other real alternative.

Comment: I think a regex is about as good as you can get, shame that `BigDecimal(x)` behaves so uselessly. You can answer your question and accept that answer if you want, that's probably better than leaving it unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much tinkering in console, I've determined that regexs are really the only way to go. I wonder if `BigDecimal`'s behavior this way is an oversight, or has some really good rationale I'm not aware of.